# Is there a bounding box function in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, python-imaging-library, jmagick

Is there a bounding box function in ImageMagick similar to the one in PIL?
Specifically one I can use with JMagick?
I'm finding it so hard to make the switch from PIL to JMagick - any good documentation out there? I've looked through the java docs and it's just not helping me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean resize to fit in a bounding box? If so, you can use `-resize WIDTHxHEIGHT` to scale an image to fit within WIDTH and HEIGHT, maintaining the original aspect ratio.

For JMagick, I guess that should translate to some resize() method.